# Use same RecyclerView.Adapter for different RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

Is it possible somehow to use same `RecyclerView.Adapter` for different `RecyclerView`? First problem is `getItemCount` method. How to know for which `RecyclerView` need to return count value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new instance of RecyclerView.Adapter, it seems like you're confused about it being a class that holds static fields, or did you really want it to have static fields? In that case I think that is a bad design decision.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter is only a way of saying to the `RecyclerView` how to create a view holder (`onCreateViewHolder`) and how to populate it (`onBindViewHolder`). The data used to fill the view's children may just be different for each adapter.

In order to use different data in each adapter create your own `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s subclass and pass the right data to its constructor (the data which will be used by the adapter itself, also by its `getItemCount()`).